# Type mismatch; need advice

Tags: vba, form-control

I have a USA coin database that I am working on and have been pulling my hair out ever since.

I have a simple table that lists all coins. There is a tick box in the table (yes/No) that signifies if I have that coin or not. A query is created from the table `qUSA`

The query is used to generate a `Form` *USA* and in the form there is an *UNBOUND* `ComboBox` that can be selected to list each denomination of coins inside the form ... e.g. 1c, 5c etc. etc.

From the form I created a button that launches a report based on the selected combo box denomination.  Also I created another button to list all the coins in the collection (i.e. when a record has a tick in the yes/no field).

It all works individually, but I now want to create another button that lists ALL 1c that's IN my collection. eg. When I want to run a report of say 1c coins but within my collection (ie with a tick in the field) I get a type mismatch error or if I fiddle with the code it gives me ALL 1c coins regardless if they are in my collection or not.

Please help. Its clear I'm not that good at VBA!!

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub ReportDenomination_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_ReportDenomination_Click

    Dim stDocName As String

    stDocName = "USA"
    strWhere1 = "[Denomination] = '" & Me.Combo16 & "'"
    strWhere2 = "[Purchased] = " & "Yes"

    DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , strWhere1 And strWhere2

Exit_ReportDenomination_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_ReportDenomination_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_ReportDenomination_Click
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `DoCmd.OpenReport` statement needs an SQL-equivalent "WHERE" statement, but you're only providing a bitwise logic one - try changing it to:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , strWhere1 & " AND " & strWhere2
```